# Jquery works in jsfiddle but not in my cart. Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, jquery

I have been working on some jQuery in jsfiddle and I currently have it working. However, when I apply the exact same script to my Expresso Store using EE it doesn't work.  It's not outputting in js errors in Firebug.  Any ideas?

Here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/NnEdM/11/

And here is my site  http://spartonenterprises.com/store/playground-mulch

Comment: I can see that in your page, you have two versions of jQuery: 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Does Firebug generate errors when there's a conflict? Could that be the problem - that the code doesn't know which version of jQuery to call? (Though I tried versions 1.7, 1.8 and 1.9 in JSFiddle. They all worked. So maybe that isn't it...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, yet not positive, you can use jQuery and jQueryUI in the same document.  At least I've never had any issues in the past.  I suspect it's a function within Expresso Store that's conflicting.  `a("form.store_product_form").delegate('[name^="modifiers"]:not(:radio)', "change", e)` possibly?  Basically what I'm attempting to do is combine three functions on .hover.  One to change the thumbnail, change the SKU and change the option value.

Comment: Gah - sorry. Not caffeinated enough, didn't register that that was jQuery and a jQuery UI. And yes, I think that's correct, you can use jQuery and jQuery UI in the same doc. I thought I saw calls to two different versions of jQuery itself. (Which is possible to do...but can sometimes cause conflicts.)

Comment: Well, 6 hours later I managed to get this sorted out.  The problem was a css issue believe it or not.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Isn't that always the way? It's a minor CSS syntax, or a space in an item name. (That particular bugbear got me last week. Everything was totally fine...but there was a space in front of a notification-template name, which meant that the form was trying to use a nonexistent template.) Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Denny is great to hear that you got it sorted out. If you want to post your solution in the answer portion then you can mark your as excepted.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the prettiest solution but, I got it working by removing the inline float:left and adding it to my css instead.  Just to pass along, I wrote this jQuery to add mouse over functionality to swap product images, change the value of my select modifier, change the SKU and price on thumbnail mouseover.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#fandeck #18 a').hover(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor','hand');
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#43').show();
            $('#selectImg').val('44').prop('selected', 'selected');
            $("#43 img").attr("src", "/images/uploads/Playground_Mulch_BLK.png")
          $('.store_product_sku').text('90509');
          $('.store_product_price').text('$7.50');

          }); 



        $('#fandeck #19 a').hover(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor','hand');
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#43').show();
            $('#selectImg').val('44').prop('selected', 'selected');
            $("#43 img").attr("src", "/images/uploads/Playground_Mulch_RD.png").fadeIn("slow");
          $('.store_product_sku').text('90509RD');
          $('.store_product_price').text('$18.00');
        });


        $('#fandeck #20 a').hover(function () {
           $(this).css('cursor','hand');
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#43').show();
            $('#selectImg').val('45').prop('selected', 'selected');
            $("#43 img").attr("src", "/images/uploads/Playground_Mulch_BRN.png").fadeIn("slow");
          $('.store_product_sku').text('90509BR');
           $('.store_product_price').text('$18.00');
        });


        $('#fandeck #21 a').hover(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#43').show();
            $('#selectImg').val('46').prop('selected', 'selected');
            $("#43 img").attr("src", "/images/uploads/Playground_Mulch_GN.png").fadeIn("slow");
          $('.store_product_sku').text('90509GN');
           $('.store_product_price').text('$18.00');
        });


        $('#fandeck #22 a').hover(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#43').show();
            $('#selectImg option[value=47]').prop('selected', 'selected');
            $("#43 img").attr("src", "/images/uploads/Playground_Mulch_BL.png").fadeIn("slow");
          $('.store_product_sku').text('90509BL');
           $('.store_product_price').text('$18.00');

       })
});

       //Image replacement for Playground Much Select
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#43').show();
        $('#selectImg').change(function () {
          var num = 43;
            $('.group').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
          if($(this).val()==num){ // Resets to Black if mouse over has changed source
            $("#43 img").attr("src", "/images/uploads/Playground_Mulch_BLK.png")    
        }
        })
```

Here is the final [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnEdM/11/) and here's final result.  http://spartonenterprises.com/store/playground-mulch